# Entropy of Joint Distribution of two IID Random Variables

Tags: joint-distribution, entropy

I have two identical probability distributions $p_1(x) = p_2(x)\ \forall x$ and wish to construct a joint distribution between them, i.e. $p(x_1,x_2) = p_1(x_1)\cdot p_2(x_2)$. Supposing I know the entropy of the univariate distribution $H(p_1) = H(p_2)$, is there a simple formula to obtain the entropy of the joint distribution H(p)?

Some sketchy calculations I did lead to to believe that $H(p) = 2 H(p_1) = 2 H(p_2)$. Is this accurate?

Comment: To be explicit, your aim was to have the two be independent? I realize it's in the title but its absence from the body text concerned me.

Comment: Entropy adds: this is its defining property.

Comment: Yes, independent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calculations are correct that $H(X_1, X_2) = 2H(X_1)$. More generally, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent then
$$H(X_1, X_2) = H(X_1) + H(X_2).$$

---

\begin{align*}
H(X, Y) &= - E\left(\log_2\left(f_{XY}(x, y)\right)\right) \\[1.3ex]
&= -E\left(\log_2\left(f_{X}(x)f_Y(y)\right)\right) &&\text{by independence} \\[1.3ex]
&= -E\left(\log_2(f_X(x)) + \log_2(f_Y(y))\right) \\[1.3ex]
&= -E\left(\log_2(f_X(x))\right) - E\left(\log_2(f_Y(y))\right) && \text{linearity of expectation} \\[1.3ex]
&= H(X) + H(Y) && \square
\end{align*}